# Shiv'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred seventy?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1103.htm#10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

170 was the number of years of actual slave labor performed by the Jews in ancient Egypt.
- Torat haMinchah, 19th sermon, page 161

170 men of Kuknos' Aramite army fell in the 3rd day of battle against the Ethiopians, while attempting to breach the wall of snakes defending the city.
- Yalkut Shimoni 168

Comment: What were the other 40?

Comment: My understanding is that the slave labor did not start until the last of Yaakov's sons to die (Levi) did so, and that that was 116 years before the exodus, which would make 116 a maximum on the number of years (and 86 a minimum, as I understand Miryam was named for the slave labor and she was 86 at the exodus. I have no source for any of this).

Comment: See Torat haMincha, ad loc. Slavery began *in earnest* after the last of Joseph's generation died. It began though much earlier, in the form of taxes or voluntary servitude.

Answer (score 1):

According to [what I can see of Google's copy of Artscroll's translation of צאינה וראינה](http://books.google.com/books?id=PCMSAQAAIAAJ&q=%22one+hundred+seventy+places+in+the+Torah%22&dq=%22one+hundred+seventy+places+in+the+Torah%22)‎, there are 170 times in the Torah where *Hashem*'s name appears before *Moshe*'s. However, according to my very limited ability to read [the original Yiddish](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42459&st=&pgnum=296), there are 175. So I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_xWFKiPJDO_I/S5ZxnBlUvWI/AAAAAAAADZk/6F7ZOFJ3WE0/s1600-h/short3.bmp

And if this astonishing matter were so, that Chetzron fathered, in the days of Moshe, when he was 170 years old, it would have been written in the Torah.

Answer (score 0):

> When Jerusalem was conquered by the
>   Crusaders in 1099, the Jewish
>   residents were annihilated. The last
>   remaining Jews, battling the invaders,
>   found refuge in a synagogue. When the
>   conquest was complete, the Crusaders
>   set the synagogue alight, burning
>   everyone inside alive. By the time the
>   RAMBAN arrived, Jewish Jerusalem had
>   been demolished and in ruin for 170
>   years, and few Jews remained in the
>   city. The continuum of Jewish life in
>   the city was rejuvenated with the
>   RAMBAN’s arrival.

http://www.rova-yehudi.org.il/en/atar-ramban.asp